# MSSQL - Lowest and 2nd lowest in one row using Row_Number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been working on a query to give me the first and second review dates for employees, and the results of the review.  The query below gives me this information in two rows (1st and 2nd RowNumber).  However I need the data to appear in one row.  Here is the query I have now:

```
SELECT EmployeeID,ReviewDate, ReviewResults FROM 
    (
    SELECT EmployeeID, ReviewDate, ReviewResults, MAX(case when RowNumber = 1 then ReviewDate end) as Lowest FROM
        (
        Select EmployeeID, a.ReviewDate, isnull(at.ReviewResults,'Not Completed') as ReviewResults,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID Order By ReviewDate) as RowNumber
        FROM Employee p
        LEFT JOIN Administration a on p.EmployeeID = a.ManagerID
        LEFT JOIN AdminText at on a.ReviewID = at.ReviewID
        GROUP BY p.EmployeeID, a.ReviewDate, at.ReviewResults
        ) as sub_inner
    WHERE ReviewDate>=ISNULL(NULL,'1/1/1900')
        And ReviewDate<dateadd(day,1,ISNULL(NULL,'1/1/3000'))
        AND RowNumber Between 1 and 2
        GROUP BY EmployeeID, ReviewDate, ReviewResults
    ) as sub_outer
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, ReviewDate, ReviewResults
```

The results look like this:

```
ID        Review Date                   ReviewResults
----      -----------------------       -------------
1         2001-07-05 07:45:00.000         No Change 
1         2001-07-28 10:00:00.000         Raise
2         2001-07-23 10:00:00.000         Promotion 
2         2001-07-28 12:45:00.000         No Change
```

What I would like is:

```
ID        Review Date1    Review Date2   ReviewResults1 ReviewResults2
----      -------------   -------------  -------------  --------------
1         2001-07-05      2001-07-28      No Change     Raise
2         2001-07-23      2001-07-28      Promotion     No Change
```

Not sure how to achieve this result?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the second row in the expected output? And your query selects `ManagerID`. Add that column too.

Comment: Edited to show that.  I took Manager ID out, the result set was from a newer run of the query, sorry about that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, [Review Date] DATETIME, ReviewResults VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1,         '2001-07-05 07:45:00.000',         'No Change'), 
(1,         '2001-07-28 10:00:00.000',         'Raise'),
(2,         '2001-07-23 10:00:00.000',         'Promotion'), 
(2,         '2001-07-28 12:45:00.000',         'No Change')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    -- You would use your above query here 
    SELECT ID, [Review Date], ReviewResults
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Review Date]) rn
    FROM @TABLE 
   )
SELECT C1.ID 
       ,C1.[Review Date]  AS [Review Date 1]
       ,C2.[Review Date]  AS [Review Date 2]
       ,C1.ReviewResults  AS [ReviewResults 1]
       ,C2.ReviewResults  AS [ReviewResults 2]       
FROM CTE C1 INNER JOIN CTE C2
ON C1.ID = C2.ID AND C1.rn +1 = C2.rn
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ ID ║      Review Date 1      ║      Review Date 2      ║ ReviewResults 1 ║ ReviewResults 2 ║
╠════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║ 2001-07-05 07:45:00.000 ║ 2001-07-28 10:00:00.000 ║ No Change       ║ Raise           ║
║  2 ║ 2001-07-23 10:00:00.000 ║ 2001-07-28 12:45:00.000 ║ Promotion       ║ No Change       ║
╚════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```